# Time in milliseconds without bc

Tags: linux

I am trying to calculate time difference before starting and after completing the script in milliseconds. is there a way simpler without using bc

i have tried with date +%s000

Comment: if you can use `ksh`(93+) or `zsh`, they both support floating point calcs inside of their `math` operator, i.e. `var=$((9.7 * 10.1)); echo $var` returns `97.97`. . You might want to extend your Q to indicate what your objection is to using `bc`. Good luck.

Comment: You have the option of wrapping the parts of your script you want to time in the system `time` command and then simply picking off either the *real*, *user*, or *sys* times, or using GNU/time and specifying the `--format` for the time of interest (e.g. *real* `%e`, *user* `%U`, or sys `%S`)

Answer (score 0):

bc would be recommended for a shell script. If you have constraint, and you have python installed, then this could work inside your script.

```
 s="start time in epoch sec"
 .... your code
 e="end time in epoch sec"
 python -c 'import sys; dt=(float(sys.argv[1])-float(sys.argv[2]))/1000.; print dt' $s $e
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're sure about the script runs in 1 second, use this:

```
TIME1=$(date +"%-3N")
sleep 0.5
TIME2=$(date +"%-3N")
SYSDELAY=$(( $TIME2 - $TIME1 ))
if [ "${SYSDELAY:0:1}" = "-" ];then
    SYSDELAY=$((1000 + $SYSDELAY))
fi
```